# AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'ndim' in GPflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, matplotlib, gpflow

I run the following code to produce a graph where the mean function, the 95% confidence interval and 10 samples from the posterior are plotted as per https://gpflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/notebooks/basics/regression.html:

```
# GPflow
Y = np.asarray(p.metrics, dtype=float).reshape(-1, 1)
X = np.asarray(p.x, dtype=float).reshape(-1, 1)

 

# scaling X and Y to magnify effects of variance
X *= .01
Y *= .01

 

plt.plot(X, Y, 'kx', mew=2)

 

k = gpflow.kernels.Matern52(lengthscales=0.05)
# k = gpflow.kernels.Polynomial(degree=4, variance=1)

 

m = gpflow.models.GPR((X, Y), k)
m.likelihood.variance.assign(0.01)

 

# code below is from the docs:
# https://gpflow.readthedocs.io/en/docupdate/notebooks/regression.html
def plot(m):
    xx = np.linspace(min(X), max(X), 150)#[:,None]
    mean, var = m.predict_y(xx)
    plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
    plt.plot(X, Y, 'kx', mew=2)
    plt.plot(xx, mean, 'b', lw=2)
    plt.fill_between(xx[:,0], mean[:,0] - 2*np.sqrt(var[:,0]), mean[:,0] + 2*np.sqrt(var[:,0]), color='blue', alpha=0.2)

 

plot(m)
plt.show()

 


## generate test points for prediction
xx = np.linspace(min(X), max(X), 100).reshape(-1, 1)  # test points must be of shape (N, D)

 

## predict mean and variance of latent GP at test points
mean, var = m.predict_f(xx)

 

## generate 10 samples from posterior
tf.random.set_seed(1)  # for reproducibility
samples = m.predict_f_samples(xx, 10)  # shape (10, 100, 1)

 


## plot
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
plt.plot(X, Y, "kx", mew=2)
plt.plot(xx, mean, "C0", lw=2)
plt.fill_between(
    xx[:, 0],
    mean[:, 0] - 1.96 * np.sqrt(var[:, 0]),
    mean[:, 0] + 1.96 * np.sqrt(var[:, 0]),
    color="C0",
    alpha=0.2,
)

 

plt.plot(xx, samples[:, :, 0].numpy().T, "C0", linewidth=0.5)
plt.show()
```

Upon running it, I get thrown the following error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-e1bf5ef03fcf> in <module>
     22 plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
     23 plt.plot(X, Y, "kx", mew=2)
---> 24 plt.plot(xx, mean, "C0", lw=2)
     25 plt.fill_between(
     26     xx[:, 0],

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py in plot(scalex, scaley, data, *args, **kwargs)
   2787     return gca().plot(
   2788         *args, scalex=scalex, scaley=scaley, **({"data": data} if data
-> 2789         is not None else {}), **kwargs)
   2790 
   2791 

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py in plot(self, scalex, scaley, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1663         """
   1664         kwargs = cbook.normalize_kwargs(kwargs, mlines.Line2D._alias_map)
-> 1665         lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]
   1666         for line in lines:
   1667             self.add_line(line)

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    223                 this += args[0],
    224                 args = args[1:]
--> 225             yield from self._plot_args(this, kwargs)
    226 
    227     def get_next_color(self):

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py in _plot_args(self, tup, kwargs)
    385         if len(tup) == 2:
    386             x = _check_1d(tup[0])
--> 387             y = _check_1d(tup[-1])
    388         else:
    389             x, y = index_of(tup[-1])

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/__init__.py in _check_1d(x)
   1400     else:
   1401         try:
-> 1402             ndim = x[:, None].ndim
   1403             # work around https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/27775
   1404             # which mean the shape is not as expected. That this ever worked

AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'ndim'
```

X and Y are two given arrays, such as:

```
Y = array([[14.13],
       [14.01],
       [13.59],
       [12.63],
       [11.44],
       [10.34],
       [ 9.3 ],
       [ 8.38],
       [ 7.49],
       [ 6.9 ],
       [ 6.72],
       [ 6.87],
       [ 7.07],
       [ 7.24],
       [ 8.36],
       [ 9.78],
       [10.64],
       [12.21],
       [12.88],
       [13.37],
       [13.57],
       [13.44],
       [13.2 ]])

X = array([[0.01],
       [0.02],
       [0.03],
       [0.04],
       [0.05],
       [0.06],
       [0.07],
       [0.08],
       [0.09],
       [0.1 ],
       [0.11],
       [0.12],
       [0.13],
       [0.14],
       [0.15],
       [0.16],
       [0.17],
       [0.18],
       [0.19],
       [0.2 ],
       [0.21],
       [0.22],
       [0.23]])
```

Comment: Hi @Daniel, I'm afraid I can't reproduce your issue: after making it runnable by adding the missing imports of numpy as np, matplotlib.pyplot as plt, and gpflow, and replacing p.metrics and p.x with np.random.randn(20), it works just fine. What versions of GPflow/TensorFlow/matplotlib/numpy are you using? It might be worth installing latest versions in a fresh (virtual) python environment. In any case, I don't believe this has anything to do with GPflow - the error message looks like you are running into a TensorFlow vs NumPy/Matplotlib issue.

Comment: Hi @STJ, thanks for checking this. I am using GPflow 2.1.4, tensorflow 2.2.2, matplotlib 3.3.2 and numpy 1.18.0

Comment: Could you try and remove all GPflow references from your example as in the following:
`import tensorflow as tf, numpy as np, matplotlib.pyplot as plt;
xx = np.linspace(0, 1, 100).reshape(-1, 1);
mean = tf.random.normal(xx.shape, dtype=tf.float64);
plt.plot(xx, mean, "C0", lw=2)`
Does this also fail for you?

Comment: This does not fail !

Comment: Hm very weird. What do `type(mean)` and `mean.shape` (this time with how you construct them through GPflow, in the failing example) evaluate to?

Comment: they evaluate to <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'> and
(150, 1), respectively

Comment: and what do type(mean) and mean.shape evaluate to when you set mean = tf.random.normal(...) which *does* work with the plotting? (this is really puzzling, I'm struggling to get any idea what might be going wrong for you!)